User response is unable to be read in script
I am producing a QC check script for my job. In it, I have set it up where you define a year, then it prompts the user with a question about what quality control types and lakes they want to run the script using (I do water quality, that's why it is lakes). I am new to r so it has been a workload just to get to this point and now I have hit a block. I think showing what I am asking will be easier than typing. Here is my code for the prompt and user response in regards to lakes.
askforLakes <- \(lakeselection){
  
  assign("lakeselection", readline("What lakes would you like to run?"))
  lakeselection <- c(unlist(strsplit(lakeselection,split = c(","))))
  lakeselection <- trimws(lakeselection)
  laketypes <- c('BVR','CMR','CHL','MNR','PRR','BRR','BHR','CFK','CRR','GRR','NRR','RRR','TAR','CCK','CBR','WFR','EFR')
  if(all(lakeselection %in% laketypes) == TRUE) {
    writeLines(paste("Lakes chosen:", list(lakeselection)))
  } else if(lakeselection == "ALL"){
    writeLines(paste("Lakes chosen:", list(laketypes)))
  } else {
    write_lines(paste("Sorry,", lakeselection, "contains a lake that is not applicable"))
  }
}

This works perfect! Yet it runs into a problem when I use the argument later in the grand function. Here at this spot, instead of filtering using all the lakes, it insteads returns at the end of the function a blank table:
'QC-Samples' <- `QC-Samples` %>% filter(substr(QC_SAMPLE,1,4)==paste(year_select)) %>% filter(substr(LOC_ID,1,3) == lakeselection)

I find that this problem only occurs when using typing in ALL as the response to the prompt, not when individually putting in the lake types. This is necessary to have as otherwise you would have to type in all 17 codes for the lakes instead. I believe the problem is that the script is not reading ALL in lakeselection as a list containing all the laketypes, and instead is taking that information as something else.
This is my first sort of in-depth project and trying to figure everything out has been a chore, but also so reewarding in the end. Any help is much appreciated and in general, any tips for cleaning up my script or better ways to automate this would be helpful. Thank you and let me know if anymore information is needed.

If the intention of selecting "ALL" is to perform no filtering (and "ALL" is not a value of LOC_ID, then you ned to do one of two things.  Either (1) in your askforlakes function, set lakeselection to laketypes if the user enters "ALL", or (2)  conditionally filter in your grand function if and only if lakeselectionis not"ALL"`.

Also, using assign is not best practice in this case.  Better, get your askforlakes function to return the selected value and assign that value to `lakeselection`` in your grand function.

I am confused as how you would go about what are saying in your last comment? Is there any way for you to provide an example of what you mean?

As requested by OP in comments.  Here's an example of how to return a value from a function and hence avoid a call to assign.  Also, since the value of lakeselection passed as an argument to the function is immediately overwritten, I have deleted it.
askForLakes <- function() {
  lakeselection <- readline("What lakes would you like to run? ")
  lakeselection <- c(unlist(strsplit(lakeselection,split = c(","))))
  lakeselection <- trimws(lakeselection)
  laketypes <- c('BVR','CMR','CHL','MNR','PRR','BRR','BHR','CFK','CRR','GRR','NRR','RRR','TAR','CCK','CBR','WFR','EFR')
  if(all(lakeselection %in% laketypes) == TRUE) {
    writeLines(paste("Lakes chosen:", list(lakeselection)))
  } else if(lakeselection == "ALL"){
    writeLines(paste("Lakes chosen:", list(laketypes)))
  } else {
    write_lines(paste("Sorry,", lakeselection, "contains a lake that is not applicable"))
  }
  lakeselection
}

> answer <- askForLakes()
What lakes would you like to run? ALL
Lakes chosen: c("BVR", "CMR", "CHL", "MNR", "PRR", "BRR", "BHR", "CFK", "CRR", "GRR", "NRR", "RRR", "TAR", "CCK", "CBR", "WFR", "EFR")
> answer
[1] "ALL"
> answer <- askForLakes()
What lakes would you like to run? BVR,CMR, BRR
Lakes chosen: c("BVR", "CMR", "BRR")
> 
> answer
[1] "BVR" "CMR" "BRR"
> 

It might help the generalisability of the function to make laketypes (and perhaps the prompt text) parameters (with useful defaults) parameters to the function.
Edit
To answer OP's question in comments:
"Aren't th[e]y already parameters inside the function?".
Not really.  To my mind, a parameter can vary.  The way you've written the funcyion, the prompt and the acceptable values are both fixed.
Here is one way to write a function that lets you change the prompt and the valid selections.
askForLakes <- function(
    prompt = "What lakes would you like to run? ",
    validSelections = c('BVR','CMR','CHL','MNR','PRR','BRR','BHR','CFK','CRR','GRR','NRR','RRR','TAR','CCK','CBR','WFR','EFR')
) {
  lakeselection <- readline(prompt)
  lakeselection <- c(unlist(strsplit(lakeselection, split = c(","))))
  lakeselection <- trimws(lakeselection)
  if(all(lakeselection %in% validSelections) == TRUE) {
    writeLines(paste("Lakes chosen:", list(lakeselection)))
  } else if(lakeselection == "ALL"){
    writeLines(paste("Lakes chosen:", list(validSelections)))
    lakeselection <- validSelections
  } else {
    write_lines(paste("Sorry,", lakeselection, "contains a lake that is not applicable"))
  }
  lakeselection
}

This works the same as the original function.  But it also lets you write things like
askForLakes(prompt = "Who are your favourite Beatles? ", c("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"))

Who are your favourite Beatles? John, Ringo
Lakes chosen: c("John", "Ringo")
[1] "John"  "Ringo"

With this greater flexibility it would make sense to refactor some of the function's internals as well so that their purpose remains clear. (And the intermediate output doesn't confuse the user by referring to lakes when the request was to choose some pop stars...

Thank you, I agree that this is a better way to structure my function. What do you mean by adding "laketypes (and perhaps the prompt text" as parameters to the function? I'm not sure what you mean as parameter. Aren't thy already parameters inside the function?
